# ProtoElectric Effect: How would this work?

Tags: electrons, collision, photoelectric-effect, protons

In the '[Photoelectric Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoelectric_effect)' setup, if I replace the light source with a 'Proton Gun', What would be the result?

I tried to search around and could shortlist a few possibilities, but am not sure if we can single out on 1 specific result.

1. They combine to form Hydrogen and emit visible light.  Ammeter would read zero.
2. Elastic Collision occurs and the metal would emit electrons.  Ammeter reads a small non-zero current and hits a saturation current value.
3. Elastic Collision occurs and the metal would emit electrons. But the protons would keep accelerating the process by staying at the emitter plate. Ammeter reads a current value that keeps increasing gradually forever.

[image]

Comment: Well, having fired lots of protons into conducting targets, you get secondary electron emission (as in a scanning electron microscope). You of course always have currents flowing because the proton beam carries charge. (3) does not happen at all.

Comment: @JonCuster: Since current is measured in the opposite direction of electron movement conventionally, would there be some amount of current addition or cancellation here when both proton/electron travel in the same or opposite direction?

Answer (score 4):

A proton beam will interact with matter according to Bethe-Bloch formula which is
$$-\frac{dE}{dx} = \left(\frac{ze^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\right)^2 \frac{4\pi Z\rho N_A}{Amv^2}\left[\ln\left(\frac{2mv^2}{I}\right)-\ln(1-\beta^2)-\beta^2\right]$$

Where $v=\beta c$ is ion velocity and $ze$ is it's charge, $m$ is the mass of electron,$N_A$ is Avogadro's number, $A,Z$ and $\rho$ are atomic mass number, atomic number and density of material in your case it is zinc. The $I$ is the mean energy required to ionize an atom in the medium, which is taken nearly as $I= Z×11 $ev

The proton beam itself is a form of current too and the current is ought to add to the circuit even if it can't ionize the electrons according to Krichoff's current law, or in principle continuity equation,

But given enough energetic beam the electrons are sure gonna get out of the surface and contribute to the current, the energy deposited to the lattice will be given by the formula above and maximum energy deposited would be according to Bragg's curve

[image: Bragg's curve]

And after that when the protons has lost all of its energy it's gonna recombine with an electron forming a hydrogen atom deep inside the lattice

Think of it like a mammoth traveling, it's gonna destroy everything in its way, an ion travels straight inside the material and deposits most of it's energy at Bragg's peak, (that's how proton therapy works)

It collides with a lot of electron (in classical sense) and still keeps a straight path as it is ~1089 times the mass of electron.

Comment: *And after that when the protons has lost all of its energy it's gonna recombine with an electron forming a hydrogen atom deep inside the lattice* ~ I assumed the hydrogen would just form at the surface and escape.  But if it forms deep inside, does it mean that we will end up with a different substance/compound after a substantial time?  ex: if I started with Zinc, wud it become Zinc Hydride or something?

Comment: Irradiating a substance can change the properties of a material and some methods like this are used to increase the shelf life of materials, the hydrogen atom would be inside the lattice and will surely change the chemical environment nearby.

Comment: Don’t forget the proton also interacts (scatters) off the atoms. You can do Rutherford Backscattering Spectrometry with protons to measure composition.

Comment: True if the material is thin i.e. less than the range of protons (given by the formula) it will do scattering, like the gold foil experiment.

Comment: No, ions will scatter off the near surface region just fine, as is done routinely in RBS.